# Dart (flutter) AES EAX mode decrypt/encrypt

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, aes

I have an encrypted (AES in EAX mode) string and nonce. I need to be able to decrypt it using Dart. But it seems there is no way to do it on string that was encrypted in EAX mode? Correct me if I'm wrong. How could I do it with Dart?

Comment: You're in luck - someone submitted a PR to pointycastle yesterday: https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/pull/166

Comment: In principle these modes of operation are not **that** hard to program anyway, this one basically is AES-CTR + AES-CMAC and a bit of formatting. I mean, compared to a lot of other cryptography :P